# Why does the Batmobile have a "NO STEP" sign?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

This (silent) video shows the Batmobile in the new Batman v Superman movie:

However, [14 seconds in](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BC8JtlKJe8g#t=14s) we see:

[image: NO STEP on the Batmobile!]

Why would the Batmobile need to have "NO STEP" on the side? Batman knows the risk and it's not like he's running a taxi service. Is Batman worried about getting a ticket from an overenthusiastic Health & Safety officer?

Comment: It's to remind him not to step there.

Comment: @Richard - does Batman really need a reminder?

Comment: The [evidence](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87536/20774) would suggest that he does

Comment: Probably to remind Robin.

Comment: Maybe they're wings - airplane wings often have a section marked "NO STEP" to denote areas where it would be unsafe for a passenger to tread (in the event of an overwing evacuation).

Comment: I have doubts that this sign will actually appear in the theatrical release. This is just early b-roll footage which has not finished going through post production (hence the silence). The sign is probably there to warn the cast and crew to not step there because that piece isn't strong enough to hold the weight of a person and would probably break. That would be an expensive mistake.

Comment: I think it has more to do with the fact that they wanted the Batmobile to look like a military aircraft, which has things like this painted on delicate control surfaces (among others). I doubt the filmmakers really understand why they're there on the aircraft parts.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson: that's probably the most realistic answer!

Comment: @JasonHutchinson Consider adding your comment as an answer.

Comment: Obviously JasonHutchinson answer is the correct one, anyone could have thought of that, that's not why this question is asked is it? We want in universe explanations, much like all the Whovians go through extreme lengths to explain every little detail :P

Comment: Also @JasonHutchinson the truth is never as funny.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat: it is not obvious to me, if Jason is correct it's great!

Comment: Maybe it's to trick SUPERMAN into not stepping there! >.>

Comment: That is odd.  It *should* be "BAT NO STEP."

Comment: The bigger question is: Why would an armored vehicle like the Batmobile have a section of the body that breaks when you step on it?

Comment: Another thought: maybe this just parodies the 1966's Batman TV series? After all everything was labeled back then - from Bat-Hook to Bat-Anti-Shark-Spray.

Comment: @nneonneo - I think the "no step" warnings on the wing are there for ground crew to prevent them from damaging a delicate or moving part of the wing. No passenger in an evacuation is going to be looking down at the wing (even if they could see the writing and it wasn't obscured by smoke, water, darkness, etc). If were truly something passengers would be expected to avoid during an evacuation, it would be mentioned during the safety briefing.

Comment: I'm sure its more just an aesthetic to remind us, the viewers, humorously that the batmobile is more like a jet fighter than an automobile.

Comment: @Richard, is your "evidence" link intended to be recursive?

Comment: @TecBrat - Yes :-) Responding to Wikis comment (does he really need a reminder?), clearly he does, or there wouldn't be a sticker.

Comment: As I posted elsewhere - there are other decals on the prop (an electric shock hazard, etc). These are very, very obviously not there for the film crew. They are there for visual interest, part of the "greebling".

Comment: If this is a safety feature, I wonder what other safety features it has. Maybe there are flashing lights and dinging noises when Batman doesn't wear his seat belt.

Comment: In [this exhibition](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3117335/The-Batmobile-Batman-V-Superman-unveiled-official-synopsis-film-released-promises-new-threat.html) (see video) the Batmobile has a **NO STEP** sign. Maybe it will be in the movie.

Comment: Obviously it's because you're only allowed to jitterbug on the Batmobile. No step dancing allowed.

Comment: It's because he likes to eat Nachos while listening to [Jethro Tull](http://www.metrolyrics.com/no-step-lyrics-jethro-tull.html)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

By popular demand, I am reposting my comment as an answer.

Just to clarify, this footage is not the finished product, so don't expect to see this sign to appear in an official release. It will most likely be digitally erased in post-production. You would not see this any more than you would see the wires that hold up the stunt men in an elaborate fight scene.

I seriously doubt the sign is there for Batman, or his damsel in distress. It is most likely put there by the prop master to alert the cast and crew not to put too much weight on that part because it would probably break, or damage something underneath the body panel. Time will tell if I am correct.

Comment: I was going to answer this exact thing, so +1. The footage shown is clearly not post-production footage, and is merely meant to show us how the prop looks and get us excited for it.

Comment: Nice idea, but not very likely. 

"No Step" signs are used on aircraft and military vehicles for very specific purposes, and the use of such a sign on a prop says this was the look they were going for.

Think about it: why'd you put a sign on a prop to instruct people in the use of it *as a prop*, when everyone using it will be instructed in its use anyway? Why'd the makers of this vehicle go to such great lengths and put so much detail on it, then put what's effectively a bright pink neon sign on it saying "this is a prop!"? It'd end up onscreen, as you see here. Prop makers don't do that.

Comment: The reason they don't do that is that "digitally erasing" stuff in every frame of a scene is expensive. Putting something like that on a prop and saying "just fix it in post!" will not get you far. 

There's a reason that every real-world set is combed for things like writing, logos and labels prior to use. Only those that are *meant* to be seen, should ever end up on camera.

Comment: @DewiMorgan There is a lot of post production cgi, the whole film will be much darker and removing this is childsplay. They have to do a lot to the batmobile post production, removing those letters won't be a problem.

Comment: @DewiMorgan I agree with Vincent on this. It doesn't take very long to erase artifacts like this with modern processing software. They can write a script that will filter out 90-99% of it automatically. There would only be a handful of frames which would need more detailed work. These would be scenes which would have closeups of the Batmobile. Mind you, that at least 75% of the film will probably have CGI composite images which will seamlessly blend into the rest of the film.

Comment: It'll be interesting to see the final version. The trailer may not have sound, but the visual production values are fairly high and the *whole point* of the trailer is that it's lovingly admiring the Batmobile from every angle. Leaving a glaring prop reminder on it just makes no sense. I think it'll be there (modulo the vissitudes of film production genereally), I suspect it's for the subconscious tie-in to aircraft.

Comment: The tech for removable signage exists (tape, magnets, whatever) and removing this sign along with all the other protective stuff that would be on the prop off-set is a whole lot cheaper than getting it removed in post.

CG is not the same as color balancing. It is very far indeed from "writing a script" to just remove every instance of "no step" from the film. Every single CG change in every single shot should be known from storyboard onwards. Each one takes money and time, which must be budgeted for in advance. A sign to be "airbrushed out whenever it drifts into shot" wouldn't fly.

Comment: If it were meanta be removed in post, it'd be dayglo, so you couldn't miss it in the cutting room. When you spend as much as they did on a workable, drivable hero prop like this, "fix it in post" is *absolutely not* an OK thing to say. Hero props must look perfect.

Props guys DO NOT get to dictate where the CGI budget will get spent. The exception is props specifically for CG, for effects impossible with a realworld prop. This class of props means getting sign-off from different people than a hero prop: mixing the two would be painful at best.

Comment: Has time told whether you're correct yet?

Answer (score 102):

I don't know how chivalrous Batman will turn out to be in this movie, but the Dark Knights of the past have had cause, once in a while, to take civilian passengers. Vicki Vale in  *Batman* and Rachel Dawes in *Batman Begins* both got to take a ride in their respective Batmobiles after being rescued by their respective Batmen.

So, even if he's not running a taxi service, it's by no means unimaginable for him to bring the Batmobile to a screeching stop, retract the hood, and grunt "Climb in!" to someone in danger. Batman has, of course, anticipated this contingency, and marked an unsafe area—to better protect the citizens of Gotham.

Comment: well explained.. logic is really sound..

Comment: “*CLIMB IN! NO, NOT THERE, IT’S DANGEROUS. WELL NO, NOT EXACTLY AS DANGEROUS AS THE JOKER, BUT— SEE, NOW YOU’VE BURNED YOUR FOOT. \*mutters\* WHY DOESN’T ANYONE EVER READ THE DAMN SIGN*”

Comment: (Warner Bros., yes, I am available for script consultancy.)

Comment: Paul - great dialog, but I'm afraid [you've got competition](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8080/143) from @ChrisB.Behrens

Comment: Or if not chivalry, it's the ultimate pickup machine. He cruises the Gotham Strip on alternate Friday nights, as shown in "Batman: After Hours" on HBO and Netflix Premium.

Comment: Also, Gordon took the Batmobile for a spin in Batman Begins.  So yes, the Batmobile is not exclusively used by Batman.  (Plus, I'm pretty sure Alfred may have snuck in a few joy rides...)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite lol : "GET IN. NO, YOU NEED TO... NOT THERE, IT'S HOT. TO THE LEFT. NO, YOUR OTHER LEFT. JUST CLIMB OVER THE... #$^DAMMIT. WHAT THE HELL IS WRONG WITH YOU? FORGET IT, JUST STAY HERE."

Comment: NO STEP doesn't have to be only a safety thing. Stepping there could actually break something.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You and Chris should get together to do some script writing. [See his handiwork for yourself](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8080/2871).

Comment: Super Villians are very vulnerable to reverse psychology....

Comment: also the parts are off the shelf and have safety warnings. Batman buys his parts he has a bat cave not a smelter and factory. lots of stuff he has is parts from factories he owns and will have warnings and other labels on them due to the fact that there off the shelf parts.

Comment: @Brad, though I'm not sure the concrete wall you're smashing through will read the sign very closely.

Comment: @PaulDraper Batman will teach it to read

Comment: Maybe they have it there to prepare of the show "Batmobile Confessions". Batman would drive around at night, pick up random people and beat confessions out of them.

Answer (score 86):

### Because it's not only batman who <s>works</s> worked on the Batmobile

Note that the earlier batmobile was designed by one man (Fox), built by others (Waynetech), driven by another (Wayne) and maintained by yet another man (Alfred).

At a minimum there are **four** and potentially *dozens* of people who've worked on the various batmobiles, any of whom could have thought that that *was* a step.

---

### Because the car is built out of stock (airplane?) parts

As [Patrick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/45103/patrick-w-mcmahon) and [Monty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87536/why-does-the-batmobile-have-a-no-step-sign/87548#comment192542_87548) have pointed out in their comments above, the parts used for the Tumbler were cannibalised from Waynetech's military assets rather than being custom-made from scratch. The same is almost certainly true for the modified Batmobile. These parts may well have been pre-painted with the "no step" designation before they were appropriated for this 'black project'

---

### So he knows where not to step

Since Bruce wasn't fundamentally involved in the *design* of the car, it's clearly in his interest to know which bits can be stepped on and which bits can't. Causing thousands of dollars of damage to his funky new Batmobile for the sake of a 1$ stencil is not a good tradeoff.

Comment: That was my thinking as well. This batmobile could be similar to the Tumbler in that it was a repurposed vehicle originally designed for a larger distribution. Therefore it would have to meet some safety regs such as caution stickers and seatbelts.

Comment: A sign you've been on the internet too long: "Tumbler" looks like it's spelled wrong.

Comment: @phantom42 A sign that the internet's been around too long: Google redirects searches for "tumbler" to "tumblr"

Comment: @phantom42 A sign you've been on the internet too long: you read "Tumbler" as "Tumblr".

Comment: I think the most important workers here are the prop masters and special effects team members, who don't want people stepping on part of their *not really armored metal* car and causing damage.

Comment: @Turch...that's...too...much.

Answer (score 28):

It could be a bit of engineer's humor on the part of Batman or the actual builder of the batmobile, like this notice on the [Space Shuttle Carrier aircraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Carrier_Aircraft):

[image]

<sub>"Shuttle mounting point" by Rob Elliott (Zeeeter at en.wikipedia) - Self-made; originally uploaded to en.wiki [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Shuttle_mounting_point.JPG#/media/File:Shuttle_mounting_point.JPG). Licensed under Public Domain via Wikimedia Commons.</sub>

Answer (score 16):

I've interpreted the evidence differently from most here.

I would be surprised if the signage doesn't make the final version.  It was placed intentionally, with very neat lettering, to give the Batmobile an 'aerospace-y' or 'high-tech' feel.

If you do a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=no%20step%20sign&client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=hodCVYO8HNLHogT9vYHoDQ&ved=0CE8Q7Ak&biw=1279&bih=1365), you'll find that most *actual* 'no step' signs (that are to keep actual people from stepping on some non-weight-bearing surface,) are brightly colored and often red or yellow.

My opinion (and that is all that it is) is that the Batmobile is so marked to give the impression that it might be subject to service by his team of engineers and/or was just provided by the manufacturer (Wayne Industries) with said marking in place.  Just like it would be for anyone who ordered one -- as if it is an actual product with all the normal safety / warning stickers in place.

Comment: An interesting theory. You'll forgive me if I hold fire on upvoting this answer until I see the official trailer footage.

Comment: Completely agree.

Just like the orange label visible at 9 seconds (and again at 17, and 26); the electric shock hazard label visible at 20 seconds; and what might be something on the roof at 22 and 27 seconds... *these are decals for visual interest.* They are not stuff put on a prop just to be removed in post. That just doesn't happen. Not ever.

Comment: I am inclined to agree. This chimes with the utilitarian military/industrial aesthetic and military aircraft often have no step markings even though you would hope that flight and ground crew would know this anyway (at least as well as batman).

Answer (score 5):

I think (as does Jason Hutchinson who mentioned this first) that it's a label for the film crew since it will obviously be some vulnerable part which cannot support the full weight of a person (or some similar reason).

Judging by the unaltered footage and no music + the fact it says [B-roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-roll) in the title this is some stock footage which got leaked or released to some network in order to create some anticipation for the upcoming movie.

I don't like this footage, if it got leaked shame on the person who did it, we've seen the batmobile in pictures and will see it in future 'REAL' teasers/trailers/clips just wait till it comes out properly.

If it was intentionally released shame on the film studio, this shows they are not putting any effort into creating a hype for the movie and does not read well for the movie (i'm going with the first option).

But yes the lable is purely for crew, it has nothing to do with things "in-universe".

Sorry to spoil it for ya but there's probably nothing more to it.

Comment: I'm would expect that any/all props that require handling by the crew have handles, or other well-known areas to apply force, just for such handling.  It is highly unlikely that anyone would need to step on that surface for the normal shooting setup.

Answer (score 4):

Why wouldn't it? If there's danger, there's danger.

You could argue that ground crew at airports and on military bases *must* be extremely well trained and would never think of stepping on the dangerous parts of aircraft, but manufacturers still plaster "NO STEP" all over them. It's a safety measure. It's a precaution.

I see no reason at all for this not to apply to the Batmobile.

Comment: You see no reason? I did put a few in the question.

Comment: @Wikis: No, you didn't. It seems like you didn't understand this answer or the notion that "not doing something isn't the opposite of doing nothing"

Answer (score 3):

Because stepping could cause damage to panel.

[image]

Seriously though, I see two possibilities:  it is not meant to be seen by the audience, only the cast and crew (as others have pointed out); or it is meant to be seen by the audience and convey the impression that this is a piece of military hardware of some kind, although obviously repurposed for Batman's use.

But we won't know until the movie comes out.

Comment: It's funny, I just envisioned that Batman was simply showing his affinity for [Jethro Tull](http://www.metrolyrics.com/no-step-lyrics-jethro-tull.html)