# What does this inscription on the Infinity Gauntlet mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, translation

I was recently re-watching **Avengers: Infinity War** and I noticed that when Spider-Man, Ironman, Dr. Strange and the GoTG try to pull the gauntlet off of Thanos' hand, there is some sort of inscription on the gauntlet.

Below is a photo of it (*pardon me if the image isn't very clear*):

[image]

What does this inscription mean?

Comment: "FRONT TOWARD ENEMY"

Comment: @Valorum or maybe - "*If found, return to Thanos*" :P

Comment: "*I'm with stupid **←***" in Dwarvish script.

Comment: "Wraithguard" - Kagrenac

Comment: ["No Step"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87536/why-does-the-batmobile-have-a-no-step-sign)

Comment: My husband went to space and all I got was this lousy gauntlet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "writing" appears to be a simple repeating pattern. As you can see from the images below (showing the film prop used in Infinity War), the pattern on the side is a repetition of the pattern on the top and other side of the gauntlet.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[The Gauntlet Prop From 'Infinity War' Is More Terrifying IRL](https://www.inverse.com/article/48216-infinity-war-gauntlet-prop-irl)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>Infinity War</sup></sub>

and this image which shows your screenshot more clearly.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>Infinity War</sup></sub>

Comment: I had to triple check to fully recognise that it's indeed that pattern on the blurry picture.

Comment: @Clockwork - The rivets make it look more like writing

Comment: @Valorum There's a joke in there about making the movie more riveting but I can't think of it right now.

Comment: @Valorum thanks for pointing it out. It did seem like some elvish engraving in the beginning though  I always thought that since the Dwarves made it, they put some sort of signature/inscription just like they did on Mjolnir